# Question about Humburger moment problem and Characteristic function.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation, moment-problem

Let $\phi(t)$ be some a contionous infinitly differentialbe function such that $\phi(0)=1$ and $\phi(t)$ is symmmetric.
 Let 
\begin{align}
m_{2n} =i^{-2n} \phi^{n}(0) 
\end{align}

Suppose, that 
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty m_{2n}^{-\frac{1}{2n}}=\infty
\end{align}

That is $m_n$'s satisfy the  [Carleman's condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman%27s_condition).

Does this imply that $\phi(t)$ is a characteristic function of some distribution?

Thanks.

Comment: Of course not. For instance, the inequality $m_4\ge m_2^2$ does not follow from Carleman's condition.

Comment: @zhoraster Of course. Thanks.  So, in Humberger problem, it is assumed that the sequence $m_{2k}$ is already a valid sequence of moments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know neither Humburger, nor Humberger problem. If you're speaking about Hamburger problem, then no, this is not assumed. Carleman's condition supplies that there is *at most* one solution to the moment problem. The *existence* of solution is provided by another condition (in fact, a criterion) that the matrix $(m_{i+j})$ is positive definite. Returning to your particular question, even if $(m_n)$ is a valid sequence of moments, $\phi$ does not need to be a characteristic function: you impose conditions in the point $0$ only, but elsewhere $\phi$ can misbehave arbitrarily. There can be some positive answers. Say, if $\phi$ is analytic, I think it can be verified (and I welcome you to) from the criterion I cite that $\phi$ is a characteristic function.

Comment: Going back to the Hamburger problem. You saying, that in the Hamburger problem we don't have to assume apriori that $(m_n)$ is a valid sequence of moments, right? But if Carleman's condition is verified then it implies a positive definite condition and  $(m_n)$ is a valid sequence of moments, is this correct?

Comment: @Boby, it doesn't imply positive definiteness.

Comment: I think showing that $\phi$ is a valid characteristic function under the assumption of analyticity is not that difficult the proof would essentially go as follows:  1) On the one hand, If $\phi$ is analytic on some neighborhood, then it has power series expansion where the coefficients are given by $\phi^n(0)/n!=\frac{(i)^n m_n}{n!}$;  2) on the other hand, since $(m_i)$ is a valid sequence of moments it corresponds to some distribution $F$ with a characteristic function $g(t)$;   3)  $g(t)$ can be written as power series where coefficient are give by $\frac{(i)^n m_n}{n!}$;

Comment: 4) by uniqueness of power series $g(t)=f(t)$ and therefore $f(t)$ is a characteristic function.

Comment: I have another question. Is there a sufficient condition (simpler than positive definite one) that guarantees that sequence of numbers is a valid sequence of moments?